# regular expression to block anchor tags in comments textarea

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone tell me please how to write a regular expression in Java or Javascript that will return false if "href", "" "www." or "http" is entered into the text area? I don't want people or bots to be able to enter those terms into the text area?

I tried `(?![http|<[^>]*>|href|www\.])[A-Za-z]` but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could try is:

```
/(http|www.|href)/g
```

the global option causes a regex to not stop at the first match.

try practicing with:

http://scriptular.com/#%28href|www.|http%29||||g||||[%22\%22href\%22%2C%20\%22\%22%20\%22www.\%22%20or%20\%22http%22]

(http://scriptular.com/)

Also, note that when you use:

```
[http|<[^>]*>|href|www\.]
```

keep in mind that brackets signify a matching or, that is,
[http|www|href] would do the same thing as [efhptrw|], i believe. 
(unless pipe works in brackets, too - can anyone clarify that?)

EDIT:

What about:

```
/(http[s]?:\/\/|www\.\S|href)/i
```

try it on this kind of test string:

```
"hrf", "hre" 
"ww."
 or "htp
"hrf", "href" 
"www."
"www. "
 or "http://
or "https://
http
```

Note that it will return *nothing at all* until the match has been completely correctly entered.
I don't think you need negative lookahead on this one.

Comment: I have used global before I am trying to use a negative lookahead where if it finds any of those things it will return false and only return true if those things are not there, most bots will add links to comments and thats what I am trying to avoid on my form, I already have a captcha in place but the comment validaiton is an extra security measure really.

Comment: then why didn't you say so?

Comment: I am writing and code actually using angular the captcha is optional, I am not sure how it will be implemented because the code will be reused it may not be used for the mobile version of the form, either way the form whether the captcha validates or not I cannot allow the links in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg = new RegExp(/(http|www.|href)/, 'g')
console.log( yourInput.value.test(reg) ); //prints true if there is http or www. or href
```